# mkdir() to apply chmod 0777 for all subdirectories created

Tags: php, file-permissions, mkdir

When I call `mkdir('/tmp/d/e/e/p/p/a/t/h/', 0777, true);` I needed all the subdirectories created so far to have the specified chmod: 0777.

What can be the shortest way for this?
I noticed that it did not happen.

```
root@server [/tmp]# ls -la /tmp/d/e/e/p/p/a/t/h/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 user group 4096 Aug  6 12:59 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 user group 4096 Aug  6 12:59 ../
```

Code:

```
<?php
mkdir('/tmp/d/e/e/p/p/a/t/h', 0777, true);
?>
```

Please have a look.

Comment: Can you explain little bit more your question, are you asking mkdir('/tmp/d/e/e/p/p/a/t/h', 0777, true); is not working??

Comment: Please explain your question, are you want "temp,d,e,e,p,p,t,h" directories are set 0777 permission OR you want create these directories with one mkdir() function

Comment: at least the final directory h/ is NOT having 0777 permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it in a single line:

```
exec('install -d -m 0777 /tmp/d/e/e/p/p/a/t/h');
```

This creates all directories recursively with the specified mask in one step.

Comment: I also needed to do **chmod -R 777 /tmp/d/** to get my answer; needed to set 0777 for all subdirectories created by this script.

Comment: umask=`umask`; umask 0000; mkdir -p /tmp/d/e/e/p/p/a/t/h; umask $unask;

Comment: or `mkdir -p /tmp/d/e/e/p/p/a/t/h && chmod 777 /tmp/d/e/e/p/p/a/t/h -R`

Comment: The goal was to set chmod 777 for all subdirectories created, d/, e/, e/, p/, p/, a/ t/, h/ at once.

Comment: @BimalPoudel using `-R` option sets recursive chmod on every subdir. `cd /tmp/ && mkdir -p d/e/e/p/p/a/t/h && chmod 777 d/e/e/p/p/a/t/h -R`

Answer (score 3):

It is like jack sleight said on a php.net (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php#96990)

you have to run a `chmod` for each of the directories of `/tmp/d/e/e/p/p/a/t/h`.

You can do it ie with a foreach loop. Something like this should work:

```
$path = "/tmp/d/e/e/p/p/a/t/h";
$dirs = explode("/", $path);
$cDirs = "";
foreach($dirs as $cDir) {
    $cDirs .= "/".$cDir;
    chmod($cDir, 0777);
}
```

**HINT:** If you are under linux you simply can run:

```
$path = "/tmp/d/e/e/p/p/a/t/h";
exec("mkdir -R ".$path);
exec("chmod -R 777 ".$path);
```